# Put Coap Works in another class

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266

I've used coap server like this :

```
coapServer coap;
coap.server(callback_light, "light");
coap.start();
```

And the callback method :

```
void callback_light(coapPacket *packet, IPAddress ip, int port,int obs) {
  ///Some Work...
}
```

and it works perfectly. 
I've made a class called COAPService and the header file :

```
#include <coap_server.h>
class COAPService
{
private:
    coapServer coap;
    int WiFiTimeOut = 5000;
    void getListOfWiFi(coapPacket *packet, IPAddress ip, int port, int obs);//id = 0 GET

public:
    COAPService();
    void COAPLoop();
};
```

and the cpp file :

```
    #include "COAPService.h"
#include <coap_server.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

COAPService::COAPService()
{
    coap.server(static_cast<COAPService*>(this)->getListOfWiFi, "wifilist");
    coap.start(5683);
}
void COAPService::getListOfWiFi(coapPacket *packet, IPAddress ip, int port, int obs) //id = 0 GET
{
    ///Some Work
}
```

My problem is in the constructor.
when i call static_cast(this)->getListOfWiFi for a callBack method it returns :

```
COAPService.cpp:7:75: error: no matching function for call to 'coapServer::server(<unresolved overloaded function type>, const char [9])'

     coap.server(static_cast<COAPService*>(this)->getListOfWiFi, "wifilist");
```

Why this error appears ?

Comment: This most definitely is not C.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. thanks.

Comment: This error is thrown at runtime right? When the COAPService() is executed?

Comment: No, while the code is verifying.

Comment: I created an answer but to clarify can you show the signature of the function `coapServer::server`?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem is that you are passing a member function pointer to `coapServer` in order to be called at some point in the future.

If this is right, I assume that the function pointer you pass as argument to `coap.server()` must be a non-member function as you didn't pass the object pointer any time.

Try to transform `getListOfWiFi` in a static one (include the keyword `static` in the function signature):

```
static void getListOfWiFi(coapPacket *packet, IPAddress ip, int port, int obs);
```

Or just declare this function outside of any class/struct.

And in the `COAPService` ctor, just pass its address:

```
COAPService::COAPService()
{
    // the static_cast you made here doesn't make much sense.
    coap.server(getListOfWiFi, "wifilist");
    coap.start(5683);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. when i declare function outside of my class the error still is returned. and when i put static before the function declaration, i can't use coap (declared in private). why ?

Comment: You are omitting the message errors, but I think it is because you declared the function as private inside the class. Try to declare the function with `public: ` before its signature.

Comment: Can you be more precise about what is going on and when the errors appear?